# Consolidating 2 generic types into one for a generic function call

Tags: generics, c#-7.0, type-constraints

I'm sorry if the title is not very descriptive I have a hard time coming up with one.

I have an abstract baseclass with a generic type as one of its properties.

```
public abstract class AdapterBase<T>
{
        public string AdapterName { get; set; }
        public T? Configuration { get; set; }
}
```

I want to derive from the abstract class and pass along the type-information of the Configuration Property.

```
public class FooAdapter : AdapterBase<FooConfiguration>{}
public class BarAdapter : AdapterBase<BarConfiguration>{}
```

Both Configuration Objects have different properties, one might have a name, the other only a Guid. However Attached to each Configuration-class I have an attribute.

```
[MyCustomAttribute("Foo")]
public class FooConfiguration{}

[MyCustomAttribute("bar")]
public class BarConfiguration{}
```

Now I want to call a generic function that only checks for the existence of the attribute in the configuration field

```
public bool AdapterConfigurationHasMyCustomAttribute<T>()
{
  ....
}
...
main()
{
   bool isThere = AdapterConfigurationHasMyCustomAttribute<FooAdapter>(); => returns true
}
```

My problem is, if I don't specify that T is of AdapterBase then I have no access to any of the properties for T inside the function.
So I have to constrain the type with a where clause

```
public bool AdapterConfigurationHasMyCustomAttribute<T>() where T : AdapterBase<U>
{
....
}
```

which would be fine for me. This solution, however, requires that I also supply the Type-Information for U which would make the signature look like this.

```
public bool AdapterConfigurationHasMyCustomAttribute<T,U>() where T : AdapterBase<U> where U: class, new()
{
....
}
```

preferably, however, I'd like to keep the signature with a single type since the type for U is already defined through by defining T. And adding another type would also mean that a call like this:
main()
{
bool isThere = AdapterConfigurationHasMyCustomAttribute<FooAdapter, BarConfiguration>();
}

would result in True, even though FooAdapter and BarConfiguration don't belong together.

I could circumvent it by passing along an object as a parameter like this.

```
public bool AdapterConfigurationHasMyCustomAttribute<T>(AdapterBase<T> myAdapter) where T : class, new()
{
....
}
```

but instantiating an object when I only need information attached to a type seems overkill to me.

Likewise I would like to **avoid** a call like this where I pass the Configuration-Type along:

```
main()
{
   bool isThere = AdapterConfigurationHasMyCustomAttribute<FooConfiguration>();
}
```

This is because if someone else were to use the code they would need to have prior knowledge about which Configuration-Type belongs to which AdapterBase-derivative or else they might make mistakes later.

```
main()
{
   BarAdapter = new BarAdapter();
   bool isThere = AdapterConfigurationHasMyCustomAttribute<FooConfiguration>();
   if(isThere)
   {
     //doing something with BarAdapter after checking FooConfiguration
   }
}
```

I'd like for the method-signature to look like this.

```
 public bool AdapterConfigurationHasMyCustomAttribute<T>() where T : AdapterBase<U> where U: class, new()
    {
    ....
    }
```

Is there a way that allows me to avoid having to pass a second type while making sure T is always a derivative of AdapterBase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you can achieve this by using reflection to inspect the attribute on T. modify your method like follow:**

```
public bool AdapterConfigurationHasMyCustomAttribute<T>() where T : AdapterBase<object>
{
    Type configType = typeof(T).GetProperty("Configuration")?.PropertyType;

    if (configType != null)
    {
        var attribute = configType.GetCustomAttribute<MyCustomAttribute>();
        if (attribute != null && attribute.SomeProperty == "desiredValue")
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

It constrains T to be a derivative of AdapterBase since you want to access the Configuration property, and its type is not known in advance.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I could have sworn that I tried the AdapterBase<object> approach only to get the compiler error CS1503 "cannot convert from TypeA to TypeB"
saying that this doesn't work because FooAdapter is not the same as AdapterBase<object>.

Yesterday I managed to find a different solution that fits my needs even better in the context of my project. However I will accept your answer as it is exactly what I was trying to achieve.